# VSCode: Assigning key binding to snippet not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to use a snippet to convert '.' to '_'. I want to bind this snippet to a shortcut key.

I included the following to `keybindings.json` file.

```
//keybindings.json
//Snippet-1
    {
        "key": "alt+u",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "${1/[.]/_/g}",
        },
    },
```

Pressing `alt+u` does not insert the snippet.

However the following works:

```
//keybindings.json
// Snippet-2
    {
        "key": "alt+u",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "${1/[.]/_/g}_more_text",
        },
    },
```

When there is some text in the snippet it works, but fails when there is no text in the snippet.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### EDIT 2020/09/03:

This snippet work in a global snippet file (as below). It fails only when I use it in a keybinding.

```
//Snippet-3

    "snake_case": {
        "prefix": "sn",
        "body":"${1/[.]/_/g}" 
    },
```

Comment: That should work (you could put a space after it and it works), so it seems like a bug.  Are you going to paste some text in there for conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a bracketed alternation group you do not need to escape literal dots, but apparently you do in snippets.  Vscode's documentation, see [transform examples](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples).  So i tried:

```
"snippet": "${1/[\\.]/_/g}"
```

and it works as you expect.  But I still think there is a bug here as merely adding a space makes your version work!

Comment: Unfortunately, your snippet is not working for me. Would you please tell me how you use this snippet. Did you use it with keybinding? Because, when I use the snippet in a global snippet file it works (Please see my edit to the question). It does not work only when I use within a keybinding. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hit `Alt+u` and then enter - by typing or pasting - some text to be transformed (dots to underscores) and press tab to see the transformed text.  Did you hit `tab`?   How exactly are you trying to use the snippet?